# Downsides to ScopedTypeVariables

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

What are the downsides to `ScopedTypeVariables`, if there are any? Why isn't it on by default? Does it lead to worse inference? Are there edge cases where it fails? Is it significantly harder to implement in GHC?

Comment: It isn't on by default for the same reason every other extension isn't on by default - it isn't part of the Haskell standard.

Comment: If that's the only disadvantage to the extension, please change this to an answer and I'll accept it. I'm aware that it's not in the standard, but I didn't want to bias the question.

Comment: I can only think of advantages with `ScopedTypeVariables`, except for a slight complication of the type checker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't on by default for the same reason every other extension isn't on by default - it isn't part of the Haskell standard.

As augustss said - this requires more logic in the type checker but I don't think anyone considers it burdensome.

Answer (score 11):

It's also because it changes the semantics of a program (combined with other extensions). Consider

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
foo :: forall a . (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
foo = bar
  where
    bar :: a -> a
    bar = id
```

It compiles fine, but with `ScopedTypeVariables` it even fails to compile.